# Can't find the reference to a library

Tags: .net, vb.net

Trying to shadow copy file from path A to Path B but it keep throwing me error message

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'AlphaVSS.x64, Version=1.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=959d3993561034e3' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format."}

Code i try with it

```vb
  Public Sub copyFile(baza As String, destination As String)

        If IO.File.Exists(baza) Then

            Dim myFileInfo As FileInfo
            myFileInfo = New FileInfo(baza)

            Dim _volume As String = myFileInfo.Directory.Root.Name

            Dim _vssImplementation As IVssImplementation = VssUtils.LoadImplementation()
            Dim _backup As IVssBackupComponents = _vssImplementation.CreateVssBackupComponents()

            _backup.InitializeForBackup(Nothing)

            _backup.GatherWriterMetadata()

            _backup.SetContext(VssVolumeSnapshotAttributes.Persistent Or VssVolumeSnapshotAttributes.NoAutoRelease)
            _backup.SetBackupState(False, True, Alphaleonis.Win32.Vss.VssBackupType.Full, False)

            Dim MyGuid01 As Guid = _backup.StartSnapshotSet()
            Dim MyGuid02 As Guid = _backup.AddToSnapshotSet(_volume, Guid.Empty)

            _backup.PrepareForBackup()
            _backup.DoSnapshotSet()

            _backup.ExposeSnapshot(MyGuid02, Nothing, VssVolumeSnapshotAttributes.ExposedLocally, "L:")

            Dim sVSSFile2 As String = baza.Replace(_volume, "L:\")

            If (File.Exists(sVSSFile2)) Then
                System.IO.File.Copy(sVSSFile2, destination + "\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(baza), True)

                For Each prop As VssSnapshotProperties In _backup.QuerySnapshots
                    If (prop.ExposedName = "L:\") Then
                        Console.WriteLine("File found !")
                        _backup.DeleteSnapshot(prop.SnapshotId, True)
                    End If
                Next

                _backup = Nothing

                Console.WriteLine("File copied")

            Else

                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------")
                Console.WriteLine("File not exist: " + baza)

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have the VSS nuget package and references

[image]

It throws error on line

```
Dim _vssImplementation As IVssImplementation = VssUtils.LoadImplementation()
```

Comment: Is that reference in your web.config?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I dont have any reference in web config . Can you explain a bit more please

Comment: Seemingly the exact same issue [here](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/2154). Have you tried installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572)?

Comment: @djv Yes i did. It ask me if i want to repair. Also i have one project in c# where everything works as a charm. But i cant figure out what is missing in my main project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://alphavss.alphaleonis.com/doc/1.4.0/). There are requirements when using the package

1. Visual C++ 2017 Redistributables must be installed on the machine running any application using AlphaVSS
2. Note that your application must be built using "Prefer 32-bit" **unchecked** if the Platform Target is set to Any CPU. Also note that your application must be built for 64-bit to work on a 64-bit system (or Any CPU with Prefer 32-bit off), and in 32-bit to work on a 32-bit system.

I initially had the same error as you, until I unchecked "Prefer 32-bit", then that line of code worked.

Comment: That still didn't solved my problem. I must go with x64 bit because of other code in project. So in compile my target cpu is set to x64 and i have the c++ redist installed :S

Comment: Yes it did, but now you have a new problem.

Comment: When i try to open a connection to OleDb.OleDbConnection it throw me `{"The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."}` So i cant go with x64

Answer (score 0):

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

This message means you're trying to load an executable (.dll, .exe, etc.) which cannot be run by the process (or by Windows itself depending on the situation).

The most common cause for this error is trying to load 32-bit code into a 64-bit process (or vice versa). 64-bit processes can only run 64-bit code, and 32-bit processes can only run 32-bit code.

Since it is the `AlphaVSS.x64` assembly that's faulting, your project is most likely compiled into a 32-bit executable. You should either remove this reference ***or*** change your project to target x64 only (note that if you do the latter you won't be able to run your application on 32-bit machines).

Answer (score 0):

Manual solution of the problem.

Open the *.csproj file with your own notepad

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="............">
.....other props...
<!-- Just add the following line here -->
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>

 </PropertyGroup>
```